# Text field with autocomplete oracle apex

Tags: oracle, autocomplete, textfield, apex, lov

I have created a function that outputs a nested table based on the email entered in a page element.
The values are fetched from the ldap.
The function works and when I call it, I get the desired values from the LDAP.

Now I have created a page element in which the email can be entered. This is of the type Text Field with autocomplete with the following SQL query in the Shared Component:

```
SELECT MAIL,USERNAME
from table(LDAP_SEARCH_BY_MAIL(:P7_EMAIL));
```

As display and return type I have selected mail.

However, when entering the mail, I do not get any suggestions based on the input.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text Field with autocomplete will accept only one column in the select query.

For example: `SELECT employee_name FROM t_empolyees;`

In the query that you have mentioned you have selected two columns.

Display and Return values are only for Select List and LOV's.